# UNINSTALL Ubuntu? Help!

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wiped Ubuntu files, bootloader still there, how can I remove it and restore Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124627/wiped-ubuntu-files-bootloader-still-there-how-can-i-remove-it-and-restore-wind)

I have read most articles on removal but to no avail!

I cannot raise Windows 7 in the start-up, it goes straight in Ubuntu. I have tried most techiques like, the F8, del button etc. on start-up.

I cannot also raise systems> administration etc. The only thing I can think of is get a windows 7 system repair disc and boot up with that?

:-/

Nigel

Comment: Actually what you want? Uninstalling ubuntu or or to give higher precedence in boot menu?

Comment: Actually what you want? Uninstalling ubuntu or or to give higher precedence for windows in boot menu?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must copy the bootloader of windows on sda:

Boot from the windows dvd and click on the cmd command line then you type in:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

I think it helps :)

Comment: Please use code formatting to make your answer easier to read.