# How to load an existing windows installation as a virtual Guest inside Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, virtualization

I dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I want to be able to virtually boot this windows installation inside Ubuntu.

While trying to do this using qemu
`qemu -hda /dev/sda -m 2048`
I am able to see the GRUB loader, I select Windows and then I just get the Blue screen of death.

So, how do I boot the existing installation of windows as a Virtual Guest in Ubuntu.

The solution need not be only qemu related. It can be any virtualization solution.

**Note:**
I don't want to convert the existing installation into a virtual disk and then use it. I want to be able to directly boot the existing windows installation.
Basically all changes made to Windows from inside Ubuntu should reflect in the native Windows installation.

Comment: Windows is known not to work well when it sees different hardware, so I rather doubt you can. Also, writig to the Windows partition from both the host and the virtual machine will likely lead the filesystem corruption - not a good idea.

Comment: for Virtual Box: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Answer (score 0):

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329

Try the above link.It will give you a hint.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.