# Running Windows 7 in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, windows-7

I have an Ubuntu 13.10/Windows 7 dual boot set up.  I am trying to figure out how to access my programs from the Windows partition, like MS Office, Skype, etc., through Ubuntu.  Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance!

drakiras

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Answer (score 0):

use wine to run windows programs on ubuntu
to get wine download it using software center or type the code given below in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

If you want to run the complete windows 7 from ubuntu you can use virtual box
virtual box is available in the softwaree center