# Virtualbox doesn't work with a real partition

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

So I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm). However, when I went to Virtualbox and told it to use the file I got the error

> Failed to open the hard disk file /home/parth/Win7.vmdk.
>
> Permission problem accessing the file for the medium '/home/parth/Win7.vmdk' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).
>
> Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
>
> Component: Medium
>
> Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
>
> Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
>
> Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The VirtualBox user should be the owner of `.vmdk` file and have read & write permissions for both `.vmdk` and the device it refers to (like `/dev/sda`). Everything in `/dev/` is owned by root, so you have two options:

1. Run VirtualBox as root. I wouldn't suggest it because such a huge application as VirtualBox potentially have bugs that are capable to crash your system being rooted.
2. Grant your user the permissions for the `.vmdk` file and the `/dev/sdX` device:

   a. Make sure `.vmdk` is somewhere in your home directory

   b. Make sure that your user is the owner of `.vmdk` and have read and write permissions for it (right click -> Properties -> Permissions)

   c. Grant your user the permissions for the device:

   `sudo chmod 666 /dev/sdX`

   (place the required device instead of `/dev/sdX`)

Comment: If you added the the group "disk" to the vboxuser/virtualbox user, make sure you reboot the Host OS or log out and login in to ensure the user can access devices whose group is "disk".

Comment: normal user add to `disk` group is dangerous, `chown/chmod` specified device is better.