# Virtualbox WIn10 from ubuntu not booting

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to virtual my Win10 installation from my HDD within ubuntu (15.04).

What I've managed so far - I created a HDD file for virtual box that is set to my win drive (/dev/sdb2).
The VM loads and hangs on boot (the pointer is just flashing).

Any ideas?
Another issue - everytime I log to ubuntu I need to change the premissions of /dev/sdb2 so Vbox can load, and ideas on this?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a real partition with Windows 7 installed, in a virtualbox vm?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm) Also http://superuser.com/q/451573/252532

Answer (score 0):

Windows won't boot on other hardware easily like linux does.

What you did is use the windows harddrive in a virtual machine - changing the whole hardware from window's point of view.

You could however make an install in virtualbox and use the raw-harddrive-partition instead of a virtual disk file, but then the installed windows would not be able to start natively without virtualbox.

Comment: You are also mistaken. I just swapped the disk from my mothers' laptop and boot it up in mine last weekend. These are two completely different devices (AMD vs Intel CPUs and graphics) and Windows survived it just fine, was usable and did re-authenticate as genuine in the original laptop after. So swapping the chipset for "virtual hardware" should work. It's certainly not a nice solution to swap back and forth, but possible. You people don't seem to know as much as you think you know and you are hesitant to even trying things out.

Comment: No need to get grumpy on the people who want to help you. Do not forget, you are asking linux users, why a windows will not boot - we tell you what we know about. Is your virtual machine at least the right architecture? x86 or x64?

Comment: I'm not grumpy at all and I'm not the OP. I have played enough in the past years to troubleshoot MBR and UEFI boot issues myself and I use Windows (at work on desk) and Linux (at home, at work dc). (And yes both machines from the example were amd64.)