# Physical disk for virtual machine

Tags: dual-boot, windows, virtualization

Is it possible to have a Virtual Machine AND a Dual Boot Windows OS alongside Ubuntu?

Currently, I'm in Ubuntu. I prefer it over Windows, but unfortunately, I need to use Windows from time to time. Is it possible to install Windows on a physical disk, and then have the option to either boot into it during startup or just connect in Ubuntu, either via remote control or virtualization?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dualboot system, and run the Windows partition in a VM, consult [this thread.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm)

You may not use remote control (RDP/VNC) without somehow booting the Windows partition in a VM, so the remote control is kind of superflous.