# GRUB rescue when running an existing Windows partition in virtualbox

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, windows, virtualization

I'm using VirtualBox in Ubuntu.
I have an existing Windows 10 partition, I created a VMDK file like below, following the instructions from [How to use a real partition with Windows 7 installed, in a virtualbox vm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm)

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename Win10.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 1,2,3,4,5
```

Then imported it to VirtualBox.
[image: screenshot of VirtualBox]

But when I run that VM, it is getting me into grub rescue command screen by showing `error: unknown filesystem`. How can I proceed?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Why is it doesn't work? I was following the instructions I found here https://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Comment: 1. Because the answer there assumes BIOS/Legacy, not UEFI and 2. The answer itself warns that it might not work (and it doesn't) and it shouldn't be tried anyway due to multiple issues you're likely to stumble upon, the least of them is the Windows activation problem.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia My windows is a genuine one, Can you tell me the exact way to run my existing windows installlation in virtualbox?

Comment: It deosn't matter how genuine it is. You'd be using the same license in a different computer, the virtualized one. It doesn't matter if the license is OEM or retail, the former isn't transferable, the latter is but can't be used in two machines simultaneously. But activation is the least of the possible problems in that usage scenario. So, I won't be telling you how to, I said NOT to do it, that's all. Bye.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The process basically worked for me (with BIOS). I used a comprehensive guide from https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dualboot-Windows_virtualisieren/.