# Removing grub from laptop

Tags: grub2

Is it possible to remove grub by doing a windows 8 refresh

Wondering if this would work as I'm doing this on a friend's system. Dont want to mess up anything. He doesn't have a CD to fix the MBR so I figured that a refresh would most likely fix it. Is this right?

Thanks!

Julian

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Windows installation DVD or repair CD, you can boot to a repair command prompt and run:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

This command installs the Windows bootloader. If you have a dual boot it would boot straight to Windows and you can then do what you want with the linux partitions.

If the *Windows refresh* you are talking about is the manufacturer-supplied option, then I doubt it will do anything with the bootloader. If you don't have a Windows installation DVD or repair CD, boot Windows and create a repair CD. Or a repair USB.

Alternatively you can use `lilo` with it's "Windows-style bootloader" option from Ubuntu, which works the same as the Windows bootloader. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71555/boot-windows-from-grub-rescue-command-prompt/71634#71634) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and download hirensbootcd (just google it) and burn the iso file to a cd. Then boot the machine from that cd. It comes with live Linux, WinXP and msdos, each with an unbelievable number of tools. There are also tools to backup/save the mbr and to replace it e.g. with a standard one windows would work with. If you want to try this, I recommend you to first boot to the cd's mini-xp and there search for the tool I described. Sorry, but I don't remember the name. If you really(!) can't find it, ask again (write me a comment) and I will search for it. Good luck!

edit: here comes the [link](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/)