# How can I reinstall Windows bootloader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I dual booted my system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.0.4.
I deleted the Ubuntu partition and now on booting the system says `error : no such partition` and `grub rescue>`.

I searched for the solution online but all the answers required me to know the partition in which Ubuntu was installed, which I don't remember, and it doesn't exist anymore since I deleted it.

Furthermore, to make things worse, I do not have the Windows repair CD so I can reinstall the bootloader.

Comment: What do you mean by you deleted the partition? Which partition did you delete do you know?

Comment: Actually you want the opposite of what you asked. You want the Windows bootloader back instead of Grub. This may help you, one of the answers suggests an alternative to Windows media: http://askubuntu.com/questions/572736/removing-grub-from-laptop . Or this: http://askubuntu.com/a/149675/589808 . Further troubleshooting is Windows only and as such off topic here.

Comment: @Jakob45 This part *which neither do I remember nor does it exist anymore since I deleted it* already says the user doesn't know. And it's kinda obvious what happened. the user deleted at least the main Ubuntu partition and probably swap as well.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I agree it looks like they have deleted a major Linux partition but I am simply trying to understand what they were doing to achieve this to try and better understand the problem

Comment: Also when you say you don't have a windows recovery disk, I believe it is possibly using your product key to download a windows 7 iso from the microsoft website. As CeltiWarrior says however we won't be able to help with that if microsoft won't play ball. [This is the link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7)

Comment: Additionally if you can prove that you own Windows, I can send you an ISO.

Comment: @Jakob45 I must have deleted the whole partition of 20 GB which I made for Ubuntu. Which includes all the 3 sub partitions including swap. I was hoping to install another OS on the system but I ended up partitioning the logical drive and when I deleted that partition, I am sure I deleted the other one, the one which had Ubuntu on it.

Comment: @MarkYisri I bought the laptop which was pre booted with Windows 7.I think I may find the invoice of the bill but I don't think I have the key of the windows. :(

Comment: @harsh Privately send someone the invoice. They can probably help you.

Comment: Have you looked on the bottom of your machine there should be a windows sticker with the key on it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to repair GRUB using the boot repair tool which is usually reasonably reliable at identifying the correct partitions etc.
You will need a live CD to boot on and then you can install the repair tool.  You need to follow the second option in this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

In short these are the commands you will need to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

NB: This will only work if all your Linux partitions are still intact (which in your case they may not be), however a report will be generated which will include a partition table which you could add to your question if this does not work.

Another option for you could be to try the repair Windows boot files under 'other options' in the advance options in boot repair. I have never made use of this option so cannot vouch for its reliability.

Comment: Actually Boot-Repair will also install the syslinux boot loader which will work to boot Windows. Windows cannot be hibernated, normally Windows 7 is not, but BIOS installs of Windows 8 or 10 maybe and then Windows repair disk required. You can also manually install syslinux or lilo boot loaders using just about any bootable Linux repair/install disk. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: @oldfred what do you mean by Windows cannot be hibernated?

Comment: The Linux NTFS driver will not mount read/write hibernated nor NTFS needing chkdsk to prevent damage. So Linux repair tools will not even see the NTFS. Applies whether UEFI  or BIOS and even if multiple booting only versions of Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation