# How to uninstall the grub bootloader?

Tags: boot, bootloader, grub-efi

I had trouble with my first installation of ubuntu so I'm trying to uninstall everything so I can do a clean reinstall.

I've deleted the partition but the problem is that the grub bootloader is still on listed in the bios boot options.

[image]

I've tried using the remove boot option feature on the bios, EasyBCD, and EasyUEFI but the grub bootloader won't go away.

Comment: You can just have a reinstall of Ubuntu!

Answer (score 2):

Parts of the bootloader are stored in the UEFI boot partition. For Ubuntu, this is only four files in a Ubuntu subdirectory:

```
EFI
EFI/ubuntu
EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
```

So, if you can manage to mount to UEFI boot partition (for example using a bootable Ubuntu USB key, choosing "Try It", and using the terminal from there), you can remove the files.

But I suggest you do not bother: when you do you reinstall, the four files will quite simply be overwritten.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to remove these files?

Comment: In Ubuntu, you'd use the `rm` command. You should read up on mount points and basic Linux/Unix commands like `rm`. There are numerous online tutorials about these subjects.

Answer (score 0):

I think reinstalling the windows bootloader will automatically overwrite GRUB bootloader.

The procedure to reinstall windows bootloader is mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149674/how-to-create-or-recover-windows-bootloader-after-deleting-ubuntu-boot-drive).

However, I don't think that's required. You can simply proceed to reinstall ubuntu without doing so. That will be a clean Install.