# I accidentally deleted all bootloaders (Windows Boot Manager and GRUB)

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I accidentally deleted all bootloaders (Windows Boot Manager and Grub).
If I start my laptop it doesn't found any bootloaders. How can I reinstall at least Windows 10 boot manager and/or GRUB afterwards?

Comment: You can easily install grub if you have live USB of Ubuntu same version that is installed in your system.. Your boot mode is BIOS or UEFI.. Can you explain how did you delete those to understand.

Comment: My Friend Filled /dev/sda1 with /dev/urandom bytes

Comment: Do you have live USB? What Version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/739431

Comment: I dualbooted windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04. I cannot boot in any of them. Right now I have xubuntu live running. I tried boot-repair. That didnt work and also Windows own startup repair didnt work

Comment: You must install grub or windows bootloader.. You killed the base.. For windows bootloader you can refer other forums.. Grub can be installed by the above link in comments. You need Ubuntu 18.04 live installer.

Comment: I do not have any bootloaders. Also not the Windows one. I tried to go in the BIOS and set a EFI File as executeable but there is none.

Comment: If you wrote 0 to sda1 & that was your FAT32 with boot flag to make it the ESP, you would have no boot loaders. Recreate sda1 as FAT32 with boot flag. Then Windows repairs & Boot-Repair's full reinstall of grub using advanced mode should work, it you did not zero out more than just the ESP. If not post link to summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create or recover Windows Bootloader after deleting Ubuntu boot drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149674/how-to-create-or-recover-windows-bootloader-after-deleting-ubuntu-boot-drive) and [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Repair restore and reinstall grub 2 with a Ubuntu installation USB or DVD disk.**

Boot from Ubuntu installation DVD or USB drive and choose 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.
Find the partitions of your Ubuntu Installation. If you are not sure which one, launch GParted (included in the Ubuntu installation DVD or USB)
or.
Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and use the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and find out the partitions.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
```

XX being the partition where Ubuntu is installed.

for example: sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt.

If there is a separate boot partition.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

XY being the boot partition

for efi boot.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXZ /mnt/boot/efi
```

XZ being the efi partition.

Now bind the directories that grub needs access to to detect other operating systems, like so.

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Now we go to that using chroot.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now install, check, and update grub.

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >/etc/resolv.conf
apt install grub-pc grub-common
```

This time you only need to add the drive letter (usually a) to replace X, for example:
for Legacy/BIOS boot:

```
grub-install --force /dev/sdX
```

for efi boot:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX
```

then

```
update-grub
```

Now grub is back, all that is left is to exit the chrooted system and unmount everything.

```
exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

Shut down and turn your computer back on, and you will be met with the default Grub2 screen.

***for more see [this link.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)***

***Windows is likely to be found by grub if not see [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/) or  [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2012/03/10/restore-the-windows-bootloader-to-mbr-after-dual-booting-with-linux/)***

In such a case you may have to repeat the whole process of  Repair restore and reinstall grub 2 with a ubuntu live cd.