# Fix renamed boot directory from grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2

I am not very clever and renamed my boot folder to boot1 to try out my own Boot folder which did not work. Now I am in rescue mode (terminal says `grub rescue>`) and I cannot start my system.

I can see using `ls (hd0, msdos1)` that this is where the files are.
So how can I rename boot to something else and then rename `boot1` to `boot`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, is it not possible to rename via the rescue terminal?

Comment: Grub is merely a bootloader. Grub Rescue is merely a fallback when a bootable partition cannot be found; it allows you to investigate and specify the bootable partition. Grub Rescue is not a shell, and lacks the capability to  manipulate files and directories. Boot from a LiveUSB instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with the LiveUSB, could someone please englighten me. I am running windows on my computer and the ruined ubuntu is on an Oracle VirtualBox

Comment: Wait I just noticed you said "..it allows you to investigate and specify the bootable partition" can I specify to boot from boot1 using rescue instead then?

Answer (score 1):

Boot with live USB or DVD.
Find the your system's  partition in Other Locations (XXGB Volume) and click on it. 
It will mount the file system.
Find the UUID of your filesystem from /media/ubuntu/

run command on terminal:

```
sudo  mv /media/ubuntu/<your-partition UUID>/boot1 /media/ubuntu/<your-partition UUID>/boot
```

Shut down and (after removing the live DVD or USB drive) start.

If it does not boot normally then [recover grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086109/i-accidentally-deleted-all-bootloaders-windows-boot-manager-and-grub/1086121#1086121).

Comment: I'm sure this could have worked, however I ended up mounting another version of ubuntu on the VM and accessing the other drive through it and changing the filename

Comment: I hope this will be helpful to some body someday.