# edit grub in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, pci, grub-legacy

I edited the grub file to include "pci=noacpi". Then each time I choose to enter Ubuntu (which is installed alongside with Win 10), it is just purple screen, refusing to enter Ubuntu.

I'm wondering if I can edit the grub file in Win 10 to remove the "pci=noacpi". I don't have the terminal in Win 10 to type "gedit/etc/default/grub"

Comment: Do you get grub menu when booting? If so you can can edit  as one time with e and scroll to linux line and remove the boot parameter. If you have grub menu have you tried recover mode, second or third menu item in grub menu.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/q/9933/301745) But it would probably be easier to use recovery mode or a live disc like Hobbyist answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit grub from Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/q/834205/301745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in Windows.

- **If you get the grub**

  1. Go to "Advanced Options" and then "Recovery Mode".
  2. Go to "Drop to root shell prompt" (terminal).
  3. `nano /etc/default/grub` and edit.
  4. `update-grub`
  5. `reboot` and you are done.
- **Otherwise**
- Repair restore and reinstall grub 2 with a Ubuntu installation USB or DVD.

Boot from Ubuntu installation DVD or USB drive and choose 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.
Mount the partition of your Ubuntu Installation. If you are not sure which one, launch GParted (included in the Ubuntu installation DVD or USB)
or.
Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and use the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and find out. It is usually a EXT4 Partition. Replace the XX with the drive letter, and partition number, for example: sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
```

XX being the partition where Ubuntu is installed.

If there is a separate boot partition.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

XY being your boot partition.

for efi boot.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXZ /mnt/boot/efi
```

sdXZ being the efi partition.

Now bind the directories that grub needs access to to detect other operating systems, like so.

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

then

```
sudo gedit /mnt/etc/default/grub
```

edit it save and go to that using chroot.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now update grub.

```
update-grub
```

Now grub is back, all that is left is to exit the chrooted system and unmount everything.

```
exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

Shut down and turn your computer back on, and you will be met with the default Grub2 screen.
Modified from [this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086109/i-accidentally-deleted-all-bootloaders-windows-boot-manager-and-grub/1086121#1086121)

Comment: It seemed like you were having some difficulty with the formatting, so I stepped in and fixed it. I think I got everything in the right place, but you might want to check.

Comment: [@wjandrea](https://askubuntu.com/users/301745/wjandrea) Thanks for the effort. I was distracted.

Comment: I used the first method and made it. Thanks. One more thing is that I have two options in the "Recovery Mode": Linux 4.18.0-11 and 4.18.0-10. Why did I have two? I just chose the 11 one.

Comment: Because you have two kernels. If you fail  in one you can use the other.