# Removing Ubuntu & Windows does not boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, uninstall, lenovo

I'm really desperate. I installed 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 7.

No Problems. Then Ubuntu did not boot. I repaired the Grub Loader, then both worked nice (though in the Grub Loader it showed two Windows 7 Loaders?). But since yesterday Windows does not boot anymore. The screen just stays black. I wanted to remove Ubuntu with this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124627/wiped-ubuntu-files-bootloader-still-there-how-can-i-remove-it-and-restore-wind).
But GParted just searches and searches and searches. Waited about 2 hours and didn't even show one partition.

Ubuntu itself has problems now. Updates throw error messages etc. Now I just want to remove Ubuntu and have my Windows 7 back. Note that I have no Windows 7 CD (Lenovo didn't send one) and my laptop has no DVD drive.

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E320.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could indicate a serious problem with your hard drive. Boot from an Ubuntu live cd/usb, start Disk Utility, select your harddrive and check your drive's health. Any number of reallocated sectors means that your drive needs to be replaced, the higher the number, the more urgent this is.

Comment: Ok here is a pic of what Disk Utility shows:
http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/1826/screenshotfrom201208040.png

Comment: With the SMART Data i get a Warning for "Current Pending Sector Count" (Value: 355 sectors). Everything else is green or N/A

Comment: I realy have no idea what that means....

Comment: It means your boot failure is related to the deteriorating condition of your hard disk. It is adviced to replace it as soon as possible.

Comment: AHH damn it! the laptop is brand new. im gonna send it back. thanks for the help